# error : Building Windows Phone application using MSBuild 64 bit is not supported

Tags: msbuild, windows-phone-8

I tried to build my first windows phone library under VisualStudio2012 with help of  task under the NAnt.

> error : Building Windows Phone application using MSBuild 64 bit is
>   not supported.

Am I right that I should use 32bit version of MSBuild, as for the WindowsPhone 7 projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are right. If you are using TFS build definitions, change the MSBuild platform to **x86**. When you edit your build definition in VS 2012, select **Process** and go into the **Advanced Settings** option and change the MSBuild Platform drop down list from **Auto** to **x86**. When the 32-bit version of MSBuild will be used and all of those 32-bit tools will produce your Windows Phone 8 libraries without a problem.

OR
if you use the MSBuild via cmd :

"*C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/**Framework**/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe"* instead of *"C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/**Framework64**/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe"* (**/p:PlatformTarget=x86**)

Comment: Thank! Sorry for the stupid questions, but I am a newbie in Windows Phone development.